# How to keep a persistent connection to SQL Server using Ruby Sequel and Tiny_TDS while in a loop

Tags: ruby, sequel, freetds, tiny-tds

I have a ruby script that needs to run continually on the server.  I've daemonized it using the daemon gem, and in my script I have it running in an infinite loop, since the daemon gem handles starting and stopping of the process that kicks off my script.  In my script, I start out by setting up my DB instance using the Sequel gem and tiny_tds. Like so:

```
DB = Sequel.connect(adapter: 'tinytds', host: MSSQLHost, database: MSSQLDatabase, user: MSSQLUser, password: MSSQLPassword)
```

Then I have a `loop do` that is my infinite loop.  Inside that, I test to see if I have a connection using `DB.test_connection` and then I query the DB every second or so to check if there is new content using a query such as:

```
DB['SELECT * FROM dbo.[MyTable]'].all do |row|
    # MY logic here
    # As part of my logic I test to see if I need to delete this row in the table and if so I use
    DB.run('DELETE FROM dbo.[MyTable] WHERE some condition')
end
```

Then at the end of my logic, just before I loop again, I do:

```
sleep 1
DB.disconnect
```

All of this works great for about an hour to an hour and a half with everything checking the table, doing the logic, deleting rows, etc., then it dies and gives me this error message `TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection timed out`

My question, why is that happening?  Do I need to reformat my code in a different way?  Why doesn't the DB.test_connection do what it is advertised to do?  The documentation on that says it checks for a connection in the connection pool, and uses it if it finds it, and creates a new one otherwise.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up just putting a rescue statement in there that caught this, and re-ran my line of code to create the DB instance, yes, it puts a warning in my log about already setting that instance, but I guess I could just make that not a contstant an that would go away.  Anyway, it appears to be working now, and the times it does timeout, I'm recovering gracefully from those.   I just wish I could have figured out why it was/is disconnecting like it is.

Comment: @user350013 any further insight?

Answer (score 1):

`DB.test_connection` just acquires a connection from the connection pool, it doesn't check that the connection is still valid (it must have been valid at one point or it wouldn't be in the pool).  There's no way that a connection is still valid without actually sending a query.  You can use the `connection_validator` extension that ships with Sequel if you want to do that automatically.

If you are loading Sequel before forking, you need to make sure you call `DB.disconnect` before forking, otherwise you can end up with multiple forked processes sharing the same connection, which can cause many different issues.

Comment: So, that didn't seem to fix it, it still timed out even when using the connection_validator.  I've now set it up to use the timeout to test for connection on every request to see if that will solve this issue.  What is the best practice when using a DB instance in an infinite loop like this?